# Black screen after logged out

Tags: logout, 19.10

After I log out of Ubuntu 19.10, the screen is blank/black instead of showing a login prompt. I have to restart the PC to log in again.

How may I troubleshoot this?

Comment: What Ubuntu version?

Comment: I am on version 19.10

Comment: @Luhein Lategan If you boot from a 19.10 LiveUSB, then log out, does the problem repeat?

Comment: I will try that and revert

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. My dell XPS running Ubuntu 19.04 and windows dual boot was running fine. I was asked to upgrade to 19.10 and started the process and walked away. When I came back there is a blank screen with a blinking cursor and I’m unable to reboot or turn off the computer. Tried ctrl alt F1-F8 but nothing worked

Comment: I eventually decided to go the easy route - reinstall Ubuntu. And all is good now, Thank you and kind regards

Comment: Okay- I also managed to restore things by forcing a shutdown (by holding power key for 15-20 seconds) and then boot up with in safe mode which allowed me to do something which fixed the issue. I think some packages werent fully installed.